# Is there a .NET control out there to emulate the Word 2007 selection toolbar?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, user-interface

[Contextual Toolbar http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9729/word2007toolbar.gif](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9729/word2007toolbar.gif)

I'd like to have a toolbar similar to the hover toolbar in Word 2007 ([see picture](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/9729/word2007toolbar.gif)) show up when I highlight text. Does this control exist (free or otherwise) or am I S.O.L. to hack it together myself?

Thanks!

If anyone has any tips on how to put this together that would be appreciated as well. I don't need the fade-in/out effects the bar has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any free way to do it, but I did find a component online that will allow you to create ribbon controls in your .NET WinForm.  Check out this site for the details: http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/

Unfortunately, the component is not free, but there is a trial available, so you can test it out before you fork out the 234 bucks to buy it.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I already have a ribbon control suite from PureComponents http://purecomponents.com/ (works well, but the documentation is a bit thin). I like the control pictured that only appears when you select text in Word.